# Distinguish Between Request Parameters in the same position?

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, httprequest

Is there a way to distinguish between request parameters in the same position in expressjs?
E.g., is there a way to have:

```
router.get('/pages/:id', function(req,res){
  var id=req.params.id;
  api.getPagebyID(id, function(err,pageData){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(pageData);
  });
});
```

And to have:

```
router.get('/pages/:name', function(req,res){
  var name=req.params.name;
  api.getPagebyName(name, function(err,pageData){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(pageData);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly set multiple middlewares for a particular pattern, but it's up to you to decide when to skip a middleware (with `next`). After a response is sent, no further middlewares are executed.

```
router.get('/pages/:id', function(req, res, next){
  var id=req.params.id;
  api.getPagebyID(id, function(err,pageData){
    console.log(pageData);
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
      if(err.error === 'not_found'){
        // No id. Try name:
        next();
      } else {
        // Actual error:
        res.status(500).send();
      }
    }
  });
});

router.get('/pages/:name', function(req,res){
  var name=req.params.name;
  api.getPagebyName(name, function(err,pageData){
      if (err) console.log(err);
      console.log(pageData);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If ID is a number, you can use regex to only match numbers:

```
router.get('/user/:id([0-9]+)', function(req, res){
  res.send('user ' + req.params.id);
});

router.get('/range/:range(\\w+\.\.\\w+)', function(req, res){
  var range = req.params.range.split('..');
  res.send('from ' + range[0] + ' to ' + range[1]);
});
```

Check out the docs here: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router.param